# Angular 2 Material - Using MD's autocomplete example in a form

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material2

Is there a way to have the autocomplete work inside a form? I have a form that takes input for an address. I'm using autocomplete ([copied from Material Design's docs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete)) for states (this is in the US) and that is working except that the selected state is not being set to user.state. So when I console log out the myForm.form.value on submit it looks like this:

```
user.name : "Test"
user.phone: ...
etc.
```

with user.state not even showing up.

My (relevant) code:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input 
    mdInput 
    placeholder="State" 
    [mdAutocomplete]="auto"
    [formControl]="stateCtrl"
    name="user.state" 
    [(ngModel)]="user.state"
  >
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete 
    #auto="mdAutocomplete"
>
  <md-option 
    *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state"
    (onSelectionChange)="selectState(state)"
  >
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```
  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,) { 
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filterStates(name));
  }

  filterStates(val: string) {
    return val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s))
               : this.states;
  }
```

Even when I try to use (onSelectionChange) to call function selectState(state) to set the user.state it still doesn't show up when I console.log the form on submit.

```
  selectState(value){
    this.user.state = value;
  }
```

Comment: Kind of confused here - first off, why are you doing both ngModel and formControl on the input for the value?  If you removed the ngModel and did a valueChanges on the formControl, does it display the value?  Do you have a formGroup as the parent to the form control?  The autocomplete should have nothing to do with the value not changing, so something is incorrectly implemented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at this GitHub example: **[Demo with md-autocomplete (forms)](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/autocomplete)**

There is an example with both reactive and template-driven form. With the template driven form you remove the `formControl` completely, and just use `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)` instead. Here's sample for you with the template-driven solution:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="tdAuto" name="state" 
       #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="currentState"
      (ngModelChange)="tdStates = filterStates(currentState)">
  </md-input-container>

  <md-autocomplete #tdAuto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of tdStates" [value]="state">
      <span>{{ state }}</span>
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>    
</form>
```

and in component we assign the filtered value to a different variable (`tdStates`) and keep all states in the `states` array:

```ts
filterStates(val: string) {
  if (val) {
    const filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
    return this.states.filter(state => state.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
  }
  return this.states;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kn6An6zOppHHV8ZeAtdA?p=preview)**

Comment: how to implement the same in dynamic rows ex: if we click plus button new row will come where autocomplete should work. ? Any idea pls?

Comment: Demo link is 404

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, I managed to get it working with mat-input and mat-autocomplete, the principle is the same. What I had to add was 'refreshing' of the this.states in the inputs (focus) method, since I have multiple inputs that should use the same variable

Answer (score 2):

I have taken the example `form` from material's website and added `md-autocomplete` to it. In the demo, you can filter and select a state from the autocomplete. When the form is submitted, you can see the value getting passed to `alert`.

HTML:

Full code in plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hle6PV?p=preview)

```
<form>

// add all form code

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" >
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state" (onSelectionChange)="selectState(state, addForm.value)">
      {{ state }}
    </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

</form>
```

app.ts:

```
selectState(state, form){
    form.state = state;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  states = [];
  tdStates = [];
  currentState = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.states= [
      {code: 'AL', name: 'Alabama'},
      {code: 'AK', name: 'Alaska'},
      {code: 'AZ', name: 'Arizona'},
      {code: 'AR', name: 'Arkansas'},
      {code: 'CA', name: 'California'},
      {code: 'CO', name: 'Colorado'},
      {code: 'CT', name: 'Connecticut'},
      {code: 'DE', name: 'Delaware'},
      {code: 'FL', name: 'Florida'},
      {code: 'GA', name: 'Georgia'},
      {code: 'HI', name: 'Hawaii'},
      {code: 'ID', name: 'Idaho'},
      {code: 'IL', name: 'Illinois'},
      {code: 'IN', name: 'Indiana'},
      {code: 'IA', name: 'Iowa'},
      {code: 'KS', name: 'Kansas'},
      {code: 'KY', name: 'Kentucky'},
      {code: 'LA', name: 'Louisiana'},
      {code: 'ME', name: 'Maine'},
      {code: 'MD', name: 'Maryland'},
      {code: 'MA', name: 'Massachusetts'},
      {code: 'MI', name: 'Michigan'},
      {code: 'MN', name: 'Minnesota'},
      {code: 'MS', name: 'Mississippi'},
      {code: 'MO', name: 'Missouri'},
      {code: 'MT', name: 'Montana'},
      {code: 'NE', name: 'Nebraska'},
      {code: 'NV', name: 'Nevada'},
      {code: 'NH', name: 'New Hampshire'},
      {code: 'NJ', name: 'New Jersey'},
      {code: 'NM', name: 'New Mexico'},
      {code: 'NY', name: 'New York'},
      {code: 'NC', name: 'North Carolina'},
      {code: 'ND', name: 'North Dakota'},
      {code: 'OH', name: 'Ohio'},
      {code: 'OK', name: 'Oklahoma'},
      {code: 'OR', name: 'Oregon'},
      {code: 'PA', name: 'Pennsylvania'},
      {code: 'RI', name: 'Rhode Island'},
      {code: 'SC', name: 'South Carolina'},
      {code: 'SD', name: 'South Dakota'},
      {code: 'TN', name: 'Tennessee'},
      {code: 'TX', name: 'Texas'},
      {code: 'UT', name: 'Utah'},
      {code: 'VT', name: 'Vermont'},
      {code: 'VA', name: 'Virginia'},
      {code: 'WA', name: 'Washington'},
      {code: 'WV', name: 'West Virginia'},
      {code: 'WI', name: 'Wisconsin'},
      {code: 'WY', name: 'Wyoming'},
    ];
  }

  filterStates(val: string) {
    if (val) {
      const filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      return this.states.filter(state => state.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }
    return this.states;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="tdAuto" name="state" 
       #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="currentState"
      (ngModelChange)="tdStates = filterStates(currentState)">
  </md-input-container>

  <md-autocomplete #tdAuto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of tdStates" [value]="state.name">
      <span>{{ state.name }}</span>
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>
```